# second order ODE via variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't understand this step on [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second_order_equation).
$$A'(x)u_1(x) + B'(x)u_2(x) = 0$$
why we desire A=A(x) and B=B(x) to be of this form? What is the basis that this form is valid?

[image]

Comment: So you ask "why". Well, just because it is useful. Have you read the entire article? Just go on, you will see what I mean and you will note how that condition is extremely useful.

Comment: Yes i read the entire article for second order ...the whole problems is solved based on this. but why this condition holds?

Comment: Well, the condition does not "hold". You simply require that A(x) and B(x) satisfy that condition. Seems incredible but it works and it simplifies next calculations; and, of course, it allows you to solve the algebraic system. Hope this helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Justifying an Assumption Made While Deriving the Method of Variation of Parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263853/justifying-an-assumption-made-while-deriving-the-method-of-variation-of-paramete)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is closely tied to the method of *osculating parameters*. 
Suppose we wish to represent, with constant coefficients, some arbitrary function $u(x)$ with two linearly independent functions $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$,
$$u(x) = A u_1(x) + B u_2(x).$$
In general this can not be done. 
The best we can do is match the value of the function and its derivative at some point $x_0$, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
u(x_0) &=& A u_1(x_0) + B u_2(x_0) \\
u'(x_0) &=& A u_1'(x_0) + B u_2'(x_0).
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The conditions above determine the osculating parameters, the constants $A$ and $B$.
$A$ and $B$ will be different depending on the point $x_0$.
In general this fit will be poor at points far from $x_0$.

The method of *variation of parameters* involves finding the osculating parameters $A$ and $B$ at every point. 
That is, we let $A$ and $B$ be functions of $x$. 
The condition that they are the osculating parameters is that they satisfy 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
u_G(x) &=& A(x) u_1(x) + B(x) u_2(x) \\
u_G'(x) &=& A(x) u_1'(x) + B(x) u_2'(x),
\end{eqnarray*}$$
just as above.
For the second equation to hold it must be the case that 
$$A'(x)u_1(x) + B'(x)u_2(x) = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx) page. In particular

> Here’s the assumption.  Simply to make the first derivative easier to deal with we are going to assume that whatever $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$ are they will satisfy the following [...]
>
> Now, there is no reason ahead of time to believe that this can be done.  However, *we will see that this will work out*.  We simply make this assumption on the hope that it won’t cause problems down the road and *to make the first derivative easier* so don’t get excited about it.