# Variation of Parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently taking a class on Fundamentals of Differential Equations. The textbook is of the same name and authored by Nagle, Saff, and Snider.

I don't completely understand the derivation of the variation of parameters method for solving an ODE. Particularly the part where we assume that the particular solution of the ODE is of the form $v_1(t)y_1(t) + v_2(t)y_2(t)$.

What allows this assumption? In my opinion it seems like a huge assumption to make.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: It's not really an assumption, it's just a guess. Since $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the homogeneous equation, a lot of things will simplify when you plug this in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Justifying an Assumption Made While Deriving the Method of Variation of Parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263853/justifying-an-assumption-made-while-deriving-the-method-of-variation-of-paramete)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing technically *allows* it, you're just asking what conditions would $v_1$ and $v_2$ have to satisfy if they happened to exist, and you get to a pair of first order differential equations. Now, if said pair of ODEs *happened* to have a solution, you would have a solution for you inhomogeneous problem. The theorem of existence and uniqueness for first order ODEs guarantees there is a pair of solutions.