# Why can't an arbitrary function $u(x)$ be represented using two linearly independent functions, $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$ having constant coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I read in an answer, regarding the justification of the assumption in the method of variation of parameters that  $u(x)=Au_1(x)+Bu_2(x)$, is not possible in general. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264193/764238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the three functions:

$f(x) =1, g(x)=x, h(x)= x^2.$

$f, g$ and $h$ are linearly independent by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

More concretely, if there were constants so that $a + bx = x^2$
Then rearranging we would have
$a + bx - x^2 = 0$
For all $x.$ this is absurd, if we plug in x big enough the left hand side will be negative. Not 0.

Comment: ok...but how about sin x and cos x? and u(x)=sin x + cos x? Can you provide a more general proof?

Comment: @DhatriDongre Trivially, if you _define_ a function $u(x) = \sin x + \cos x,$ then this particular $u(x)$ that you have defined is a linear combination of $\sin x$ and $\cos x.$ There are infinitely many other functions that also are linear combinations of $\sin x$ and $\cos x.$ The point is that no matter which two functions you choose as $u_1$ and $u_2,$ there will be an infinite number of functions that can be written in the form $Au_1(x)+Bu_2(x),$ and an infinite number that **cannot** be written in the form $Au_1(x)+Bu_2(x).$

Comment: "not possible in general" means that it cannot be done for all triples of functions. As you've shown, it is possible by accident.