# Why is this constraint justified when constructing a Green's function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, greens-function

Let's consider a linear operator $L$ such that
$$Ly = f$$
subject to some homogeneous boundary conditions on the interval $[a,b]$. The homogeneous solution is
$$y_h(x) = c_1y_1(x) + c_2y_2(x)$$
for real constants $c_1, c_2$.
Now, according to my notes in class, we assume that the particular solution is
$$y_p(x) = u(x)y_1(x) + v(x) y_2(x)$$
Once we define this function, I see that this constraint to $u(x),v(x)$ was imposed,
$$u'(x)y_1(x) + v'(x) y_2(x) = 0 $$
This constraint seems to be key to solve the problem, as after simplifying the equation $Ly_p = f$, we can solve for $u(x),v(x)$ by solving the system:
$$ u'y_1' + v'y_2' = \frac{f}{p} \\
u'y_1 + v'y_2 = 0$$

My question is, where did the constraint $$u'y_1 + v'y_2 = 0$$ come from? And why is it valid?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215632/variation-of-parameters-why-do-we-assume-the-constraint-v-1-leftt-righty or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263853/justifying-an-assumption-made-while-deriving-the-method-of-variation-of-paramete

Comment: @projectilemotion thanks for the input!