# ODE analysis problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Given an IVP
$$y''(t)+(1+t^2)y=0 \quad y(0)=1, y'(0)=0$$
(a) Show that it is equivalent to
$$y(t)=\cos(t)+\int_{0}^{t} s^2\sin(s-t)y(s) ds$$

My methods:
For the reverse part, I am able to deduce that the given integral equation is the solution of the IVP by direct differentiation.

However, for the front part, I am not able to finish it. First, characteristic equation $r^2=-(1+t^2)$ gives me two complex roots. Hence,
$$y(t)=A\cos(\sqrt{1+t^2}t) +B\sin(\sqrt{1+t^2}t)$$
Use the IVP $y(0)=1$, $A=1$ and $B=0$. Hence,
$$y(t)=\cos(\sqrt{1+t^2}t)$$
Then, how can I continue??

Comment: Your method works when  $r$ is a constant. The equation has variable coefficients so the solution you have obtained is not correct.

Comment: Then, solving this equation should use another method?? Is there a "name" for that method so that I can try to figure it out.\

Comment: It would be slightly more accurate to integrate the instant frequency to get an approximate phase, with $t=\sinh(u)$ one gets $$\phi(t)=\int\sqrt{1+t^2}dt=\int\cosh^2(u)du=\tfrac12t\sqrt{1+t^2}+\tfrac12\text{Arsinh}(t)$$ and $y(t)\approx A\cos(\phi(t))+B\sin(\phi(t))$, again with $A=1$, $B=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the formula for the [variation of constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) to the equation
$$
y''(t)+y(t)=f(t)~~\text{ where }~~ f(t)=-t^2y(t).
$$
There
$$
y(t)=c_1(t)\cos(t)+c_2(t)\sin(t)\\
y'(t)=-c_1(t)\sin(t)+c_2(t)\cos(t)
$$
with the conditions
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
c_1'(t)\cos(t)+c_2'(t)\sin(t)&=0\\
-c_1'(t)\sin(t)+c_2'(t)\cos(t)&=f(t)
\end{aligned}\right\}
\implies
\left\{\begin{aligned}
c_1'(t)&=-\sin(t)f(t)\\
c_2'(t)&=\cos(t)f(t)
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
so that
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
c_1(t)&=c_1(0)-\int_0^t\sin(s)f(s)\,ds\\
c_2(t)&=c_2(0)+\int_0^t\cos(s)f(s)\,ds
\end{aligned}\right\}
$$
Combining these formulas, inserting the initial condition at $t=0$ and applying trigonometric identities leads then to the given formula.
\begin{align}
y(t)&=\left(1-\int_0^t\sin(s)f(s)\,ds\right)\cos(t)+\left(\int_0^t\cos(s)f(s)\,ds\right)\sin(t)\\
&=\cos(t)+\int_0^t[-\sin(s)\cos(t)+\cos(s)\sin(t)]f(s)\,ds\\
&=\cos(t)-\int_0^t\sin(t-s)\,s^2\,y(s)\,ds.
\end{align}

---

In a similar way, if you take any other frequency $\omega$ and consider the function
$$
g_t(s)=ω\cos(ω(t-s))y(s)+\sin(ω(t-s))y'(s)
$$
you get the derivative
$$
g_t'(s)=\sin(ω(t-s))(ω^2y(s)+y''(s))=\sin(ω(t-s))(ω^2-1-s^2)y(s)
$$
Now integrating both sides from $0$ to $t$ gives
$$
ωy(t)-\bigl[ω\cos(ωt)y(0)+\sin(ωt)y'(0)\bigr]=g_t(t)-g_t(0)=\int_0^t\sin(ω(t-s))(ω^2-1-s^2)y(s)\,ds.
$$
With for example $ω=\frac54$ the factor $(ω^2-1-s^2)=(\frac9{16}-s^2)$ is balanced in value for $s\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to spend more time to understand and try myself.

Comment: Yet, I saw a other methods: integrate the function directly:
$$y"(t)+y(t)+t^2y(t)=0$$
$$y'(t)-y'(0)+\int_{0}^{t}y(t) dt + \int_{0}^{t} t^2y(t) dt =0  \quad y'(0)=0$$
Then, integrate again and have
$$y(t)-y(0)-\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}{t}y(s) dsdt + \int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t} s^2y(s) dsdt =0$$
$$y(t)-y(0)-\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)y(s) ds + \int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t} s^2y(s) dsdt =0$$

And where I was stuck is the third integral $\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t} s^2y(s) dsdt$. I don't know how to simplify and continue. And by the way, it seems this method cannot reach the answer there is no any trigo function

Comment: This is essentially the Taylor formula with integral remainder term, $$y(t)=y(0)+y'(0)t+\int_0^t(t-s)y''(s)\,ds.$$ Now insert $y''(s)=-(1+s^2)y(s)$. If one does the limits carefully you get this also from the second approach for $ω\to 0$ as then $\sin(ωx)/ω\to x$.

Comment: I am sorry....I still cannot figure it out using the first method u mentioned in the first time. How to combine the formulas and apply trigo to lead to the desired integral equation? @LutzL

Comment: Done, it is really that simple, just use $\sin(t-s)=\sin(t)\cos(s)-\cos(t)\sin(s)$.

Comment: Let me spend some time on it... Really Thanks to your help. I will read and see where I went wrong in my work.

Comment: I find somewhere I don't understand:
Why $y'(t)=-c_1(t)\sin(t)+c_2(t)\cos(t)$? For $y(t)$, $y'(t)$ should have two more terms $c_1'(t)\cos(t)+c_2'(t)\sin(t)$. And later on you set a condition that these two terms are $0$. Furthermore, how does the seond condition -$c_1'(t)\sin(t)+c_2'(t)\cos(t)=f(t)$ comes from?
Finally, how can these equations combine to give $c'_1(t)$ and $c'_2(t)$? If I can understand how to get $c'_1(t)$ and $c'_2(t)$, then everything after that is also able to solve by myself. So, my question is all about the beginning. @LutzL

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Comment: You make a parametrization of the solution with two unknown functions, but the solution is only one function. Thus you have one functional relation of the coefficient functions for free that you can use to simplify the derivatives. Or you argue from the POV of the first order system so that then using the fundamental matrix/solution $$\pmatrix{y\\y'}=\pmatrix{y_1&y_2\\y_1'&y_2'}\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2}.$$

Comment: See also [Method of Variation of Parameters - Assigning zero works?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/844150/115115)